# GWT's SplitLayoutPanel : get resize notification

Tags: gwt, resize, splitter

I have this requirement where I only have one large widget set inside SplitLayoutPanel on the North.

As soon as the panel is resized using the splitter, I should get a notification with the values - How much has been expanded or collapsed.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

[`SplitLayoutPanel`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SplitLayoutPanel.html) implements [`ProvidesResize`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ProvidesResize.html) interface. It means, that

> (...) the implementing widget will call `RequiresResize.onResize()` on its children whenever their size may have changed.

So, if only your *large widget set inside SplitLayoutPanel on the North* implements [`RequiresResize`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RequiresResize.html), it will be notified that it's size may have changed.

The last thing you need is to get the new size. You can use [`getWidgetSize`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockLayoutPanel.html#getWidgetSize-com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget-) method.

Please, notice, that the *size* you'll get is just one dimension. For *North* pane it is *height*.

---

Simple example code:

```
final SplitLayoutPanel splitLayoutPanel = new SplitLayoutPanel();

@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {
    splitLayoutPanel.addNorth(new MyResizeWidget(), 100);
    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(splitLayoutPanel);
}

public class MyResizeWidget extends Button implements RequiresResize {
    public MyResizeWidget() {
        super("Hello!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResize() {
        this.setText("Hello! " + splitLayoutPanel.getWidgetSize(this).toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Adam. Your suggestion mostly worked. But it did not meet this particular requirement where the 1st widget present should overlap the 2nd widget when expanded.

Instead it is pushing the 2nd widget downwards. I mean, assume that the SplitLayoutPanel has 2 widgets, both added to the North portions. Now pulling the splitter down should make the 1st widget overlap the 2nd widget (1st widget should keep occupying the 2nd widget's real-estate) 

Is this possible?

Comment: I suggest that you use a _wrapper_ widget that contains those 2 widgets. A wrapper should implement `RequiresResize` and when resized it can set the first widget's size to, for example 60% of wrapper size, and the second to 50%.